# Draw a line in JAVA with Pattern - Beginner

Tags: java, drawing, line

I want to draw a line in java. I will use these draws with making Triangles. I can do this :

```
1***
11**
111*
1111
```

and i need to do this:

```
1***
*1**
**1*
***1
```

Ive done a lot of work today and my mind got really confused.

Can you help me ? Thanks A lot.

EDIT: also my perfect answer should be Implement Bresenham’s line drawing algorithm but i dont understand in wikipedia.

EDIT 2: my grid code :

```
String [][] matrix = new String [50][50];
for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++){
  for (int column = 0; column < 50; column++){
    matrix [row][column] = "*";
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need to use "nested for loops"

Comment: I have a 50x50 grid a matrix which fulled with "*" and i need Line matrix which i wrote like 2. code in question. but i can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
          int size=50;
          String[][] matrix= new String [size][size];

          for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
          {
              for (int j=0; j < size; j++)
              {
               if (i != j)
               matrix[i][j]="*";

               else
               matrix[i][j]="1";
              }
         }

         for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
         {
             for (int j=0; j < size; j++)
             {
              System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
             }     

             System.out.println();
         }

     }
}
```

Edit: if it's already filled with `*` simply make `matrix[i][j]="1";` when i equals j, ie `if (i==j)`.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for your help. This is working but i need all algorithms of line drawing include ;
`*****`
`*****`
`11111`
`*****`
`*****`
i mean this diagonal line is just my example.
Thanks a lot again this info makes my mind more brighter..

Comment: No one is going to do that for you.  It seemed like you didn't do anything except for create a matrix of *, so I assumed that you were very lost and hence provided this simple solution.  As for implementing his algorithm, it should be trivial given that there is pseudocode/actual code posted everywhere.

Comment: Edit: not trying to be mean, but people aren't just going to do everything for you. We're here to provide help/guidance, not complete homework/projects/jobs.  If you can't understand the pseudocode or how to implement it in java, perhaps you should start off with a slightly simpler example and then work your way up.

Comment: i already said that , am i not? I dont understand pseucode of  Implement Bresenham's line drawing. Im lookng for a person who want to help me about understanding this pseucode. Okay i will start from more beginner , thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this website does not really help people understand concepts with respect to pseudocode.  This is a programming website to help you with coding problems.  If you attempt the code and run into issues, someone will help you with that, but not with going through an algorithm that you have not tried to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MulArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * 1*** 1** 1* 1
         */

        String[][] grid = new String[5][5];

        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length-1; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                if (row == column) {
                    grid[row][column] = "1";
                } else {
                    grid[row][column] = "*";
                }
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length-1; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < grid[row].length; column++) {
                if (column != 4) {
                    System.out.print(grid[row][column]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }

            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your answer to include some information about how this code works and how it solves the question that was asked?